# Amazon PAAPIV5 - Validar campos en array si son NULL

Tags: php, array, validación

Recorro el array de los resultados por medio de un for pero me encuentro con que si algún valor de los que consulto no existe el for se corta y de 8 resultados me trae solamente los primeros resultados validos devolviendome un Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getAmount() on null (en este caso no hay datos en getAmount()

Mi pregunta es cual seria la forma correcta de validar el campo y si no existe modificar la varible, probe con If !empty isset pero no me funciono.

un poco de código a modo de ejemplo:

```
<?php
   
   $itemCount = 8; 
   $searchItemsResponse = $apiInstance->searchItems($searchItemsRequest);

   for ($i=0; $i < $itemCount ; $i++) {
   $itemtest = $searchItemsResponse->getSearchResult()->getItems()[$i];
   $precio = $itemtest->getOffers()->getListings()->getPrice()->getAmount();
   }


?>
```

Me gustaria logral que la variable precio tome el valor que trae de la consulta por medio de los getters pero en caso de NULL o vacio se modifique por un mensaje ejemplo $precio = "Consultar";

Desde ya muchas gracias.

---

**print($itemtest);**

Item sin precio:

```
        {
"ASIN": "B08XYRDSL7",
"DetailPageURL": "https:\/\/www.amazon.com\/dp\/B08XYRDSL7?tag=regalos01f-20&linkCode=osi&th=1&psc=1",
"Images": {
    "Primary": {
        "Medium": {
            "URL": "https:\/\/m.media-amazon.com\/images\/I\/31igWfQ637L._SL160_.jpg",
            "Height": 160,
            "Width": 160
        }
    }
},
"ItemInfo": {
    "ByLineInfo": {
        "Brand": {
            "DisplayValue": "HP",
            "Label": "Brand",
            "Locale": "en_US"
        },
        "Manufacturer": {
            "DisplayValue": "HP Printers",
            "Label": "Manufacturer",
            "Locale": "en_US"
        }
    },
    "Features": {
        "DisplayValues": [
            "BEST FOR BASIC PRINTING \u2013 Print basic color documents like recipes, forms and travel documents",
            "KEY FEATURES \u2013 Print, copy and scan in color, auto document feeder, mobile fax, mobile and wireless printing",
            "HP+ SMART PRINTING SYSTEM \u2013 The optional HP+ system enables your printer to think ahead so it's more secure, more productive and ready when you are. Requires an HP account, internet connection and use of only Original HP Ink for the life of the printer.",
            "6 FREE MONTHS OF INSTANT INK & AN EXTRA YEAR OF HP WARRANTY \u2013 when you activate optional HP+ and Instant Ink when setting up your printer. Only with HP+.",
            "EASY SETUP \u2013 Get started fast on any device with the HP Smart app that guides you step by step.",
            "HP SMART APP \u2013 Print, scan and copy from your phone\u2014whenever, wherever. Get advanced features for 24 months with HP+.",
            "WORRY-FREE WIRELESS \u2013 Get better range and more reliable connections using dual-band Wi-Fi with self-reset.",
            "INK DELIVERED BEFORE YOU RUN OUT \u2013 Never run out of ink with an optional Instant Ink subscription. Try free for 6 months with HP+. Credit card required; change or cancel anytime."
        ],
        "Label": "Features",
        "Locale": "en_US"
    },
    "ManufactureInfo": {
        "ItemPartNumber": {
            "DisplayValue": "26Q90A#B1H",
            "Label": "PartNumber",
            "Locale": "en_US"
        },
        "Model": {
            "DisplayValue": "DJ 4155e",
            "Label": "Model",
            "Locale": "en_US"
        },
        "Warranty": {
            "DisplayValue": "HP standard 1-year limited warranty, extended to 2 years with HP+ registration",
            "Label": "Warranty",
            "Locale": "en_US"
        }
    },
    "ProductInfo": {
        "Color": {
            "DisplayValue": "white",
            "Label": "Color",
            "Locale": "en_US"
        },
        "ItemDimensions": {
            "Height": {
                "DisplayValue": 7.87,
                "Label": "Height",
                "Locale": "en_US",
                "Unit": "Inches"
            },
            "Length": {
                "DisplayValue": 16.85,
                "Label": "Length",
                "Locale": "en_US",
                "Unit": "Inches"
            },
            "Weight": {
                "DisplayValue": 10.6,
                "Label": "Weight",
                "Locale": "en_US",
                "Unit": "Pounds"
            },
            "Width": {
                "DisplayValue": 13.07,
                "Label": "Width",
                "Locale": "en_US",
                "Unit": "Inches"
            }
        },
        "ReleaseDate": {
            "DisplayValue": "2021-04-18T00:00:01Z",
            "Label": "ReleaseDate",
            "Locale": "en_US"
        },
        "Size": {
            "DisplayValue": "Standard",
            "Label": "Size",
            "Locale": "en_US"
        },
        "UnitCount": {
            "DisplayValue": 1,
            "Label": "NumberOfItems",
            "Locale": "en_US"
        }
    },
    "Title": {
        "DisplayValue": "HP DeskJet 4155e All-in-One Wireless Color Printer, with bonus 6 months free Instant Ink with HP+ (26Q90A)",
        "Label": "Title",
        "Locale": "en_US"
    }
},
"Offers": {
    "Listings": [
        {
            "DeliveryInfo": {
                "IsFreeShippingEligible": true,
                "IsPrimeEligible": true
            },
            "Id": "Cp0oAeaX2ZG7e2yWmsdd5HLFuw52di7vvTsd0qmSXl113xlphevNCc9XS4Py6t8fxmO7YOrDLgMvmlWQv6tthg8yj3HuZ2rwHmZWMr3kYbxvkHNMrfuw6g%3D%3D",
            "ViolatesMAP": true
        }
    ]
}
```

**Diferencia Item con precio**

```
    "Offers": {
    "Listings": [
        {
            "DeliveryInfo": {
                "IsFreeShippingEligible": true,
                "IsPrimeEligible": true
            },
            "Id": "Cp0oAeaX2ZEdzZYRlATlZ9M%2FodKT6gjV7QUZ0eTV2pYJ40TsuuDYAZGJJJ3CXo%2FdDxBfXqTIrRBJdExIg4tslIaGil0jRUcAs0wOUagbd%2B5nXVKQATQpLA%3D%3D",
            "Price": {
                "Amount": 99.99,
                "Currency": "USD",
                "DisplayAmount": "$99.99"
            },
            "ViolatesMAP": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Quizas no me explique bien, lo que estoy considerando de hacer es darle el valor del getter a $precio pero si esta vacio/null que modifique la variable por un mensaje.

Comment: Así imprime tal cual `print($itemtest);`?

Comment: No, es la parte en donde radica mi problema.. el resto de la información ¿de que serviria?

Comment: Para saber como se accede a `Price`, puede ser algo como `$itemtest['algo']['algoMas']...` o `$itemtest->algo->algoMas`... utiliza `print_r($itemtest)` y copia y pega tal cual aparezca

Comment: Perfecto. No queria agregar codigo de gusto. Ahi edite entonces print de Item sin precio y la diferencia de uno con precio que seria todo lo mismo pero solo cambia el OFFERS

Comment: Ok, un intento más: crea una variable `$prueba= $precio = $itemtest->getOffers()->getListings()->getPrice()` justo abajo de la línea `$itemtest = $searchItemsResponse->getSearchResult()->getItems()[$i];` y luego haz `print_r($prueba)`

Comment: Lo hice y me genera el error de siempre.

Comment: Perfecto, ya vimos cuál es el método que regresa el error, ok, ahora último intento. quita el método `getPrice()` en prueba, así `$prueba= $itemtest->getOffers()->getListings()` y luego haz `print_r($prueba)`

Comment: Sisi, el método que genera el error es getOffers() y el motivo es por que durante el for en los items que no tiene precio no se genera "Price": {
                "Amount": 99.99,
                "Currency": "USD",
                "DisplayAmount": "$99.99"
            },  (por eso te indique la diferencia de un item con precio y uno sin en el print) entonces lo que estoy buscando es la manera de preguntar o validar antes de que vaya a buscarlo por que sino rompe.

Comment: No, el método que genera el problema debe ser `getPrice()` porque las dos respuestas con o sin precio tienen `Listings`, por eso quería ver el resultado de `$prueba= $itemtest->getOffers()->getListings()` y luego haz `print_r($prueba)`. El método Listings no debe de fallar porque ambas respuestas lo tienen, pero el contenido es diferente

Comment: Entiendo el punto. Al hacer lo que me pedis me devuelve un NOTICE 
Array to string conversion

Comment: Ok, muy bien, si estas utilizando PHP 8 entonces puedes utilizar el `NullSafe operator` (Usando `?->`) para `getPrice()`. Intenta esto, `$prueba = $itemtest->getOffers()->getListings()?->getPrice()` y luego en lugar de `print_f($prueba)` haz `var_dump($prueba)`

Comment: Pase a PHP 8 ejecuto el var_dump y me devuelve pantalla en blanco.

Comment: Ok, perdona la demora, tenía que dormir. Probaste con `print_f($prueba)`?

Comment: Hola disculpa la demora tambien. con print_f pantalla en blanco tambien (si hay algun notice no lo veo por que estoy trabajando directamente en el server con php 8 y estan OFF)

Comment: Ya veo, y con el `NullSafe operator` sigue fallando el programa? Lo puedes probar de la siguiente forma `$$amount = $itemtest?->getOffers()?->getListings()?->getPrice()?->getAmount();` utilizando el `$itemtest` de mi respuesta inicial y luego `$precio = $amount ? $amount : 'Consultar';`

Comment: La función se ejecuta correctamente sin las líneas mencionadas en tu último comentario al agregar $amount = $itemtest?->getOffers()?->getListings()?->getPrice()?->getAmount(); me devuelve pantalla en blanco como si se rompiera (sin error) el codigo.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar el [operador ternario](https://www.neoguias.com/if-abreviado-en-php-el-operador-ternario/) para hacer una comparación en una sola línea, o bien utilizar un `if`

En el siguiente ejemplo estoy agregando una variable `$amount` para que el código sea más claro, pero podrías no utilizarla

```
<?php
   
   $itemCount = 8; 
   $searchItemsResponse = $apiInstance->searchItems($searchItemsRequest);

   for ($i=0; $i < $itemCount ; $i++) {
       $itemtest = $searchItemsResponse->getSearchResult()->getItems()[$i];
       $amount = $itemtest->getOffers()->getListings()->getPrice()->getAmount();
       $precio = $amount ? $amount : 'Consultar';
   }
?>
```

Explicación:

El operador ternario es como un `if`, el primer parámetro es la condición, en este caso `$amount`, es decir, si $amount es diferente a `0` o `null` la condición será verdadera

Después del signo de interrogación se pone la acción a ejecutar en caso de que la condición sea verdadera, es decir, asigna el valor de `$amount` a `$precio`

Después de los dos puntos `:` se pone la acción a ejecutar en caso de que la condición sea falsa, es decir, si `$amount` es `0` o `null`, en este caso se asigna `Consultar` a la variable `$precio`

La representación gráfica de la explicación anterior sería:

```
(Condición) ? (Acción si la condición es verdadera) : (Acción si la condición es falsa)
```

Otra opción sería utilizar un `if`

```
<?php
   
   $itemCount = 8; 
   $searchItemsResponse = $apiInstance->searchItems($searchItemsRequest);

   for ($i=0; $i < $itemCount ; $i++) {
       $itemtest = $searchItemsResponse->getSearchResult()->getItems()[$i];
       $amount = $itemtest->getOffers()->getListings()->getPrice()->getAmount();
       if ($amount) {
           $precio = $amount;
       }
       else {
           $precio = 'Consultar';
       }
   }
?>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu pronta respuesta, es lo que intentaba hacer mas que nada con el IF ya que no conocia el operador tenario. Al hacerlo con el IF tal como me indicas o intentando realizar una comparación ejemplo $amount == NULL  me devuelve un Fatal Error Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getAmount() on null osea que no llega al IF sino que entiendo que se rompe al momento de asignarle el valor a $amount. Al chequear el array con print_r veo que se crea el indice (ya que lo pido en la consulta) pero vuelve vacio/null

Comment: Ah, entonces tu problema no es tal como lo describes en tu pregunta, el problema viene de la función `getAmount()` o algún punto antes de eso. Te recomiendo que hagas `print($itemtest)` justo después de `$itemtest = $searchItemsResponse->getSearchResult()->getItems()[$i];` así vas a poder ver si `$itemtest` es null, entonces aplicas la misma estrategia, hacer un `if` o con el operador ternario pero en `$itemtest`. Pero primero verifica si `$itemtest` devuelve valores para todos los valores de `$i`

Comment: Borre el comentario para darle formato pero creo que me entendiste, de todas formas ¿como puedo validar y evitar que se rompa si durante el recorrido del for 1 item no tiene el contenido que si tiene el otro item?

Comment: ¿Puedes editar tu pregunta y agregar lo que tiene `$itemtest` cuando tiene la información completa y cuando no? De esa forma puedo editar mi respuesta y que refleje la solución al problema

Comment: Pregunta editada